# Google Spreadsheets as JSON

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-get, google-sheets-api

I want to know if and how is it possible to get data from *specific cells* of a Google spreadsheet **without** publishing the sheet as public using **HTTP GET** request to fetch data in **JSON** format.

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could just create a doGet() that returns a JSON object and then publish your project as a Webapp. Then make get requests to that URL.

```
function doGet() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById('SPREADSHEET ID HERE')
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange('A1')
    .getValue();

  var stringified = JSON.stringify({cellValue: cell});
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(stringified);
}
```

EDIT: You could even put in some URL parameters and make it return specific cells. [Read more here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters)